# cannot convert from IEnumerable<string> to char

Tags: c#

```cs
private async Task<string> GenerateQueryAsync(string month, IEnumerable<string> includedUsers)
{
    var queryTemplate = await _settingsService.GetAsync("Sat_Retest_Query_Template");
    var sb = new StringBuilder(queryTemplate.Value);
    sb.Replace("{startDate}", month + "/01");
    sb.Replace("{endDate}", GetNextYearMonth(month) + "/01");
    sb.Replace("{includedUsers}", includedUsers);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

How do I resolve

> Cannot convert from `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>` to `char`

for `IncludeUsers`?

Comment: `How do I resolve` - stop trying to pass `IEnumerable<string>` which none of the [`Replace` overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.replace?view=net-6.0) accept?

Comment: What outcome do you expect?

Comment: `includedUsers` has multiple strings, you don't mention in what format you want to concatenate those strings (commas, spaces, etc). So you better make a single string out of you values, and then use it in a `Replace`

Comment: sb.Replace("{includedUsers}", includedUsers); there is an error cannot convert from string to char in this part

Comment: `includedUsers` has multiple string values. You will have to convert this to a _single_ string value before you can replace.

Comment: Please tell us you are not constructing a SQL Query like this, are you?

Comment: jql not sql @Fildor

Comment: @maya You might want to use the [Atlassian.SDK.JqlBuilder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Atlassian.SDK.JqlBuilder) package to construct the jql. This package provides a fluent API for creating JQL queries of any complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the IEnumerable<string> to some form of string that makes sense in your situation.

As an example, this shows how you can convert it into a CSV, e.g. ["one", "two"] becomes "one, two"

```
var includedUsersCsv = string.Join(", ", includedUsers);
sb.Replace("{includedUsers}", includedUsersCsv);
```